# check url with google, safe = active

Tags: php, curl

how can I check if url is displayed by google or not?

Example:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=redtubex.xxx&safe=active
```

Code:

```
$input = 'http://www.example.com';
$input = trim($input, '/');
if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input))
{
     $input = 'http://' . $input;
}

$urlParts = parse_url($input);
$domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);
$request = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='.$domain.'&safe=active/';

$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match_all('/<cite.*?>(.*?)<\/cite>/', $data, $matches); 
foreach ($matches as $fmatch)
{
    echo $fmatch[1]);
}
```

Comment: after `curl_exec($ch)` `echo curl_getinfo($ch);` use this function for info that your curl is run successfully or not

Comment: curl run successfully and I have result, but i need exact info if url is displayed by google or not.

Comment: @rafig What you mean by `displayed by google`?

Comment: see my example above. you can't see the redbutex.xxx in google serps if safe=active

Comment: Have you got the solution?