# php strpos multiple, string inside html tag

Tags: php, url, curl, strpos

my Domainname from input is:

`example.com`

curl `$data` gives me this, always different:

between `<span></span>` is the domain name.

`1. <span>example.com</span>
2. <span>www.example.com</span>
3. <span>http://example.com</span>
4. <span>https://example.com</span>
5. <span>https://example.com/</span>
6. <span>https://example.com/categories</span>
7. <span><b>www</b>.<b>example</b>.<b>com</b></span>
8. <span><b>www</b>.<b>example.com</b></span>
9. <span>Not included</span>`

the professionals have a good solution for me? fals one is found should be stopped.

My current code fails unfortunately. :-(

```
              $dname = array($d1, $d2, $d3, $d4, $d5, $d6, $d7, $d8, $d9);

              $pos = strpos($data, $dname);

              if ($pos !== false) {
                 echo 'YES';
              } else { 
                 echo 'NO'
              }
```

Comment: I think you need to be more specific as to what you want to accomplish...

Comment: see above, I have updated my question. data comes from curl and my domainname comes from input.

Comment: The second argument in `strpos` should be a single value, not an array. You might want to iterate through the array using a loop. Also, the `echo` part is incorrect - you should replace it with `echo 'YES';` and `echo 'NO';` respectively.

Comment: thanks @rhino. my original code looks little different, without `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use regex:

```
preg_match_all('~<span>(.*)</span>~Ui',$data,$domains);
print_r($domains[1]);
```

That would give you list of domain names.

Or in your case, you could use function called `strip_tags()`, this one would simply remove `span` tags, and leave what was inside. Then you could simply `explode("\n",$stripped_string);`

Aafter that, you can use function `in_array()` that would check if given domain is in array or not, or... `array_diff()`, that would compare array with given and return elements that are not in there.

For example:

```
$data = <curl_result>;
preg_match_all('~<span>(.*)</span>~Ui',$data,$domains); // this finds all domains in span tags
$domains = array_map('trim',$domains[1]); // this rewrites results and removes blank spaces
$seeking = array('domain1.com','domain2.com');
foreach($seeking as $needle){
   if(in_array($needle,$domains) !== false)
      echo "Domain $needle was found!<br />";
   else
      echo "Domain $needle was not found!<br />";
}
```

Comment: how to remove all html tags within `<span> </span>` ? and final `</span>` is not important, makes rather complicated.

Comment: function `strip_tags()` removes all html tags, but did you at least try my example? `preg_match_all()` is better solution, because when there are no new lines or spaces between `span` tags, by stripping tags, you would get something like `domain1.comdomain2.comdomain3.com`

Comment: does not working. Inside city tag is only one domain and not more. every curl gives a different composition of the domain within cite tag. Honestly this is the google search with `safe = active`. Domain is located between `<cite> </cite>`

see my previous question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709868/check-url-with-google-safe-active)

not blocked domains you can find inside cite tag but every time in different composition.

Answer (score 0):

PHP expects the second argument of `strpos` to be a string, otherwise `it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character` (as states [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)). What you have provided as the argument is an array. You could loop through the array and check whether each element in it is found in the `$data` string. The code could look like this:

```
$found = array();

foreach ($dname as $key => $val)
    $found[$key] = strpos($data, $val);
```

Here an array called `$found` is created and then populated with values returned by `strpos` for each consecutive element of `$dname`. You can then check `$found(index)` to find out if the specific element was found in `$data`.

To simply check whether any of the elements of `$dname` was found in `$data`, use the following code:

```
$found = false;

foreach($dname as $val) {
    if (strpos($data, $val) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I need only> found or not found. you mean this working for me> `if (!$found)`

Comment: I've updated my answer again. I think now it does what you expect. This way you can do `if (!$found)` to see if the string matched none of the elements.